# Installed Magento in my server but I forgot admin user name & password & email

Tags: password-recovery, change-password

Please help me on this project.

I am trying change my website User name & Password & Admin Email Id.

I can not find it. In my php my admin, Please find the attachment. Showing like this. How to can i change it?

Swamy Simon[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please one file in root with below code and run php file like magentostoreurl/filename.php so that add new admin you can use that one.

```
<?php

require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

try {
$user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')
->setData(array(
'username'  => 'newadmin',
'firstname' => 'newadmin',
'lastname'    => 'newadmin',
'email'     => 'newadmin@newadmin.com',
'password'  =>'admin@123',
'is_active' => 1
))->save();

} catch (Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
exit;
}

//Assign Role Id
try {
$user->setRoleIds(array(1))  //Administrator role id is 1 ,Here you can assign other roles ids
->setRoleUserId($user->getUserId())
->saveRelations();

} catch (Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
exit;
}

echo "User created successfully";

?>
```

Comment: actually this is my admin url: "http://www.1800recalls.com/index.php/admin" but in my filemanager i did not found any "admin" forlder name OR can i create admin folder in my filemanager can i add this file?

Comment: please make one file createadmin.php in your root folder and then copy and above code in file and run this url  http://www.1800recalls.com/http://www.1800recalls.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting any data from admin_user table then just create a new user in **admin_user** table of your Magento Store. Input the data in table i.e username, password, email

Comment: Hi, Thanks. In my php my admin when click admin_user showing like this image: http://1800recalls.com/Capture1.JPG, Please check the image screenshot. after click user name: http://1800recalls.com/Capture2.JPG

Comment: Go to insert tab and input your username, password, email